# Word Order with Relative Clause

Tags: sentence-structure

Are both of these sentences correct?

> Wir müssen heute die Etiketten für die Waren austauschen, die im Angebot sind

> Wir müssen heute die Etiketten für die Waren, die im Angebot sind, austauschen

Comment: Both sentences are correct, except for "Heute", which mustn't be capitalized. I'd (ever so slightly) prefer the second form because of "better rhythm", but that is probably highly subjective.

Comment: Both is (or are) grammatically possible and the meaning is the same. Personally, I don't even have a preference...

Comment: Both are wrong, since they don't start with a capital letter and are missing a sentence mark (beside the "heute", which has already been noted).

Comment: @bakunin I actually read something on that recently and the recommended "preference" was to use the first form just because the clause in between can sometimes become rather long. For example: "Wir müssen heute die Etiketten für die Waren, die im Angebot für unseren glücklichen Künden sind, austauschen." So would you say instead if it's shorter, the 2nd is preferred, but if it's longer, the 1st is preferred?

Comment: @BlauKakapoW: I can't say either. My comment was based on gut feeling and I couldn't, for the life of me, say, why I would prefer the one or the other.

Answer (score 1):

Both sentences are correct, but they have slightly different structures and emphasis:

1. **"Wir müssen heute die Etiketten für die Waren austauschen, die im Angebot sind."**

   In this sentence, "die im Angebot sind" is a relative clause that directly modifies "die Waren." The sentence emphasizes that the labels need to be exchanged specifically for the goods that are on offer today.
2. **"Wir müssen heute die Etiketten für die Waren, die im Angebot sind, austauschen."**

   In this sentence, "die im Angebot sind" is also a relative clause, but it is set off by commas. This structure places a bit more emphasis on the fact that the goods are on offer while still conveying the same overall meaning as the first sentence.

Both sentences are grammatically correct and convey the same basic idea, but the choice between them might depend on the context or the specific emphasis you want to convey.

Comment: "Today" is related to the exchange of the labels, not on the offer. Emphasis can be put on various parts of each sentence, no matter where they occur.

Answer (score 0):

Both sentences are correct and fine.

Be careful, however, because the relative clause "binds" strongest to its nearest fitting noun.

> Wir müssen heute die Etiketten für die Waren austauschen, die im Angebot sind

With the relative clause external to the noun-verb bracket (Waren...austauschen) you could maybe start to assume that it's the labels that are on sale (even if it's obvious from context).